# One submit to make a Query in HTML-ASP page and a normal submit

Tags: asp-classic

I want to have a Query been executed when I press the button, then follow filling other filds.  Everything works fine if I only execute the Query, but I put the other steps then the Query is not executed.
I will really appreciate any kind of help
Here are the codes :

```
<form action="" method="POST">

<%
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.Open(Server.Mappath("/db/TextDB.mdb"))

set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
sql="SELECT Country FROM TheCountries ORDER BY Country"
rs.Open sql,conn

country=request.form("country")

%>

Select the Country <select name="country">
<%  do until rs.EOF
    response.write("<option")
    if rs.fields("country")=country then
      response.write(" selected")
    end if
    response.write(">")
    response.write(rs.fields("Country"))
    rs.MoveNext
loop
rs.Close
set rs=Nothing %>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Show Countries">

<%
if country<>"" then
   sql="SELECT Country, City, Cost FROM TheCities WHERE country='" & country & "' Order by City" 
   set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
   rs.Open sql,conn

city=request.form("city")
cost=request.form("cost")

%>
<br>

Select The City <select name="city">,
<%  do until rs.EOF
    response.write("<option")
    if rs.fields("city")=city then
      response.write(" selected")
    end if
    response.write(">")
    response.write(rs.fields("City") & "   " & rs.fields("Codigo"))
    rs.MoveNext
loop
rs.Close
conn.Close
set rs=Nothing
set conn=Nothing%>
</select>
<%  end if %>
</form>


<center>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="80%"><tr><td>

<form action="_gdForm/webformmailer.asp" method="POST" target="_top" class="formmargin">
<input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="ramon_batista@hotmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="subject"  value="WebSite Contact">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/thanksespanol.htm">
<input type="hidden" name="required" value="your_name,phone,country,city">
<input type="hidden" name="sort" value="your_name,phone,country,city">

<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr><td>

Name:<br>

</td></tr><tr><td>
<input type="text" name="your_name" size="40" class="shadeform"><br>
</td></tr><tr><td>


</td></tr><tr><td>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="myscrip.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@user633228: You've got two `form`s. The first query isn't part of the second `form` which is why it isn't submitting along with it. What you can perhaps do is only display the first form and then only show the second one with

```
If country <> "" Then
    ' Show other form
End If
```

Add another `<input type="hidden" name="country" value="<%=country %>">` to the second form so `country`'s value will be sent along.